# Top questions order tabs on profile appearing wrong

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface

When viewing your profiles "Profile" page the section "Top Questions" has some sort and order tabs on it. I can't remember last time I looked but today when I looked they appear to be in the wrong order, note especially the `|` to separate the ordering and sorting actions.

[image: Problem example]

This is on Windows 10, Chrome 58 and IE 11.